# Sharing Resources across WebGLRendering Contexts

Tags: webgl

Does anybody know about present and future of [*Sharing Resources across WebGLRendering Contexts*](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/SharedResouces) ?

Now I make hidden gl handler that makes me useful images in the "timeout process"(I cant use main context for creation my little images), then I create samplers from these images in the main context. I think sharing resources between webgl contexts could help me out.

Comment: Nothing more than [this](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5486563022602240) ? Try asking at the [webgl-dev list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/webgl-dev-list) or wait for @gman to appear ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the current plans are. It seems to have become a low-priority. Partly because they first have to decide how they want to expose WebGL in workers since being able to multi-task would be huge and that really affects how sharing would work.

There's [a separate proposal for allowing 1 context to draw to multiple canvases](https://wiki.whatwg.org/index.php?title=CanvasInWorkers) but no movement there either

Comment: Gman! I've learned your great tutorials. Thanks!